# Intermittently application is not able to send message on ActiceMQ "Classic" due to javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

The application uses pooled JMS connection. On startup the application is working fine, but after a couple of days it is not able to send messages to ActiveMQ "Classic." As soon as the application is restarted it connects again and works fine for the next couple of days.

Below is the error message:
The initial error is:

```
2023-09-18 00:03:15,051 ERROR c.n.v.r.i.l.BulkMessageStorageQueueListener [pool-7-thread-1] Exception in sending messages, rollbacking messages with size: 78
org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.InitializationException: Could not instantiate mapper : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.InitializationException: Could not instantiate mapper : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:274) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:691) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.project.xxx.BulkMessageSender.sendStatusMessage(BulkMessageSender.java:71) ~[classes/:04.17.02.35]
    at com.project.xxx.BulkMessageStorageQueueListener.lambda$setupConsumer$0(BulkMessageStorageQueueListener.java:113) ~[classes/:04.17.02.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.InitializationException: Could not instantiate mapper : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:162) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:167) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:208) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:495) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.InitializationException: Could not instantiate mapper : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapperDynamically(XStream.java:646) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapper(XStream.java:616) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:587) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:515) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:484) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:430) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:369) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.XStreamSupport.createXStream(XStreamSupport.java:31) ~[activemq-stomp-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.xstream.XStreamWireFormat.createXStream(XStreamWireFormat.java:127) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.xstream.XStreamWireFormat.getXStream(XStreamWireFormat.java:113) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.xstream.XStreamWireFormat.marshalText(XStreamWireFormat.java:89) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.oneway(HttpClientTransport.java:106) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1392) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1486) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:329) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.makeSession(ConnectionPool.java:112) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:82) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:78) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:342) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:265) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:144) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:167) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:208) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:495) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.EnumMapper
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:148) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapperDynamically(XStream.java:642) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapper(XStream.java:616) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:587) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:515) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:484) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:430) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:369) ~[xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:1.4.11.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.XStreamSupport.createXStream(XStreamSupport.java:31) ~[activemq-stomp-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.xstream.XStreamWireFormat.createXStream(XStreamWireFormat.java:127) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.xstream.XStreamWireFormat.getXStream(XStreamWireFormat.java:113) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.xstream.XStreamWireFormat.marshalText(XStreamWireFormat.java:89) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.oneway(HttpClientTransport.java:106) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1392) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1486) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:329) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.makeSession(ConnectionPool.java:112) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:82) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool$1.makeObject(ConnectionPool.java:78) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:342) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:265) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.ConnectionPool.createSession(ConnectionPool.java:144) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnection.createSession(PooledConnection.java:167) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:208) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:495) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 more
```

After the below error is coming continuously until the application has not restarted.

```
2023-09-18 00:03:16,363 ERROR c.n.v.r.i.l.BulkMessageStorageQueueListener [pool-7-thread-1] Exception in sending messages, rollbacking messages with size: 94
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: https://hostName:443/destination-name?useInactivityMonitor=false. Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/apache/http/client/version.properties]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:691) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.project.xxx.BulkMessageSender.sendStatusMessage(BulkMessageSender.java:71) ~[classes/:04.17.02.35]
    at com.project.xxx.BulkMessageStorageQueueListener.lambda$setupConsumer$0(BulkMessageStorageQueueListener.java:113) ~[classes/:04.17.02.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Error while attempting to add new Connection to the pool
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createJmsException(PooledConnectionFactory.java:279) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:230) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:209) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: https://hostName:443/destination-name?useInactivityMonitor=false. Reason: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/apache/http/client/version.properties]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:374) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:288) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:97) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:94) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.addObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1238) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:226) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:209) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/apache/http/client/version.properties]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1427) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1135) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.util.VersionInfo.loadVersionInfo(VersionInfo.java:233) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.util.VersionInfo.getUserAgent(VersionInfo.java:319) ~[httpcore-4.4.13.jar:4.4.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:1057) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.createHttpClient(HttpClientTransport.java:347) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.getReceiveHttpClient(HttpClientTransport.java:233) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.doStart(HttpClientTransport.java:250) ~[activemq-http-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:354) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244) ~[activemq-client-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:288) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:97) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory$1.makeObject(PooledConnectionFactory.java:94) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1041) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.addObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1238) ~[commons-pool2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:226) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:209) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.15.12.jar:5.15.12]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-jms-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 11 more
```

Below is code for configuring the client application:

```java
public class ActiveMQConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActiveMQConfig.class);

    // Active Mq properties

    @Value("${activeMQ.broker.url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${jms.listener.concurrency}")
    private String concurrency;
    
    // The duration between attempts to redliver a message
    @Value("${jms.rollback.redelivery.delay:10000}")
    private int redeliveryDelay;

    // Maximum number of times a redlivery of a message will be attempted -1 is infinite
    @Value("${jms.rollback.maximum.redeliveries:-1}")
    private String maximumRedelivery;

    @Value("${message.activeMQ.pool.max.connections:10}")
    private int activeMqPoolMaxConnections;

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
            @Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactoryActiveMQ") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setAutoStartup(false);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler -> logger.error("An error has occurred in the transaction: {}",
                errorHandler.getMessage()));
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactoryActiveMQ() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        
        // create re-delivery policy to configure re-attempt count and delay
        // when message is rolled back on queue in case of any exception
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(Integer.parseInt(maximumRedelivery));
        redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(redeliveryDelay);
        
        connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplateActiveMQ(PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(false);
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
        pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(activeMqPoolMaxConnections);
        return pooledConnectionFactory;

    }

}
```

Note:

- activeMqPoolMaxConnections is 10.
- Message inflow is not too high. It's like 400-500 messages.
- We are also using `JMSXGroupID` to group messages (`message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", groupId);`)
- ActiveMQ connection url is `activeMQ.broker.url=https://dummy.dns.name.com/destination-name?useInactivityMonitor=false`

Comment: Based on the stack-trace it looks like you're using the HTTP transport. Is that correct? If so, is there a particular reason you're using it? Could you use the normal TCP transport instead? It looks like your use of the HTTP transport is tied directly to the problem(s) you're experiencing.

Comment: Posting the connection URI you are using is usually a helpful addition.

Comment: @JustinBertram we have 2 separate applications and there is a firewall in between, due to security reasons, we have to use HTTPS.

Comment: @TimBish connection URI is as below activeMQ.brokerurl=https://dummy.dns.name.com:443/destination-name?useInactivityMonitor=false

Comment: This looks like a bug in the HTTP transport so if you have no choice but to use it then I would recommend trying to upgrade since ActiveMQ 5.15.12 is over 3 years old now. That said, the HTTP transport isn't commonly used so an upgrade may not resolve the issue. You might also consider migrating to [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) (i.e. the next-generation broker from ActiveMQ) which also [supports HTTP](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html#configuring-netty-http).

Comment: @JustinBertram is there any other option or workaround, as ActiveMQ is common between many services so an upgrade is not feasible as of now. Can you give more details or reason of this issue.